# find and replace text from urls in csv data feed Debian 7

Tags: linux, search-and-replace

My server OS is Debian 7.
I want to add id say 'xyz' to the below URLs
[image]

```
example.com/abc.html?id=White
example.com/abc.html?id=Black
```

Then URLs should look like

```
example.com/abc.html?id=White&trackId=xyz
example.com/abc.html?id=Black&trackId=xyz
```

In data feed there are lots of URLs and there could be any color mentioned in front of ?id=

I want to add cron job for this, to download the feed and add id to the URLs.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to append trackId=xyz to the end of each URL:

```
awk '{print $0 "&trackId=xyz"}'  <in.txt  >out.txt
```